# How to get the latest xml file from a directory using powershell and parsing its data

Tags: xml, powershell

I am trying to fetch the latest XML file from a folder although able to bring the data but getting the below error

```
Cannot convert value "ResultFile_10.xml" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "The specified node cannot be inserted as the 
valid child of this node, because the specified node is the wrong type."
At line:1 char:1
+ [xml]$sdfd = Get-ChildItem C:\PowershellCode -File | Sort-Object Last ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [], ArgumentTransformationMetadataException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```

This is the code that I am using to fetch the latest XML file from a folder and then I am parsing the XML file

```
  [xml]$sdfd = Get-ChildItem C:\PowershellCode -File | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending| Select-Object -First 1   $sdfd.testsuites.testsuite | ForEach-Object {
     
     [pscustomobject]@{
         TestSuiteName = $_.name
         TotalExecutionList = $_.tests
         Failures = $_.failures
     }  }
```

But with the single file it's working fine for me

```
[xml]$xmlAttr = Get-Content -Path D:\Agent_2.xml

$xmlAttr.testsuites.testsuite | ForEach-Object {
     
     [pscustomobject]@{
         TestSuiteName = $_.name
         TotalExecutionList = $_.tests
         Failures = $_.failures
     }
 }
```

**Output**

> TestSuiteName=Open Mail; TotalExecutionList=2; Failures=0
>
> This is my below XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<testsuites>
  <testsuite name="Open Google" tests="2" failures="0" skipped="0" time="30.0730982" timestamp="2022-10-21T05:24:31" id="3a03345d-9024-6c4a-d9be-56ca477ffd21" log="">
    <testcase name="Opengoogle" time="6380192668.742" timestamp="" log="+ Passed Opengoogle&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed  OpenUrl&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;" />
    <testcase name="Print the PDF Report" time="63801926694.7071" timestamp="" log="+ Passed Print the PDF Report&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed  Print PDF Report Of TestCases {LogInfo='Started 'C:\Tosca_Projects\TCShell\Execution.bat' with arguments 'General Google &quot;/Uesrs/Deepak Shaw/CICD/DEX/TVIA/Open Google&quot;''}&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;" />
  </testsuite>
  <testsuite name="Open Mail" tests="2" failures="0" skipped="0" time="16.8880552" timestamp="2022-10-21T05:25:36" id="3a0335a8-f76b-3d18-f1d2-82680602c3d0" log="">
    <testcase name="Open Gmail" time="63801926742.2266" timestamp="" log="+ Passed Open Gmail&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed  OpenUrl&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;" />
    <testcase name="Print the PDF Report" time="63801926746.5905" timestamp="" log="+ Passed Print the PDF Report&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed  Print PDF Report Of TestCases {LogInfo='Started 'C:\Tosca_Projects\TCShell\Execution.bat' with arguments 'General OpenMailQA &quot;/Uesrs/Deepak Shaw/CICD/DEX/TVIA/Open Mail&quot;''}&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;" />
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

Comment: In the first example (the one that fails) you only list the xml-file (`Get-ChildItem`) and never seem to be reading the contents of said file the way you do in your second example (`Get-Content`).

Comment: [xml]$sdfd = Get-ChildItem C:\ -File | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending| Select-Object -First 1 | Get-Content   (pipeing with Get-Content would do it for me thanks @notjustme thanks for your suggestion)